# Capturar ação de determinados botões em um JFrame

Tags: java, swing, teclado, jframe

Criei um `JFrame` que, ao clicar os botões do teclado: cima, baixo, esquerda e
direita, deveria ocorrer uma determinada ação (um Joption no caso).

Para isso estou usando um `KeyListener`, mas infelizmente eu clico nos determinados botões e nada acontece.

```
package projeto;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class teste extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public teste() {
        initComponents();
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        cima = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Jogo do Monstro");
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(550, 700));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        cima.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

                if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "esquerda");
                } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "direita");
                } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "cima");
                } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "baixo");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jogoDoMonstro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jogoDoMonstro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jogoDoMonstro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jogoDoMonstro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new teste().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JLabel cima;}
```

Comment: As ações dos botoes devem ocorrer no jframe? Porque estão sendo aplicadas num jlabel.

Comment: @diegofm tanto faz, no caso estou usando um joption, mas nenhuma ação acontece

Comment: @diegofm eu só quero que qualquer ação aconteça, é para um fim didatico

Comment: Tanto faz nao, se as ações devem ocorrer no jframe, a ação deve ser aplicada a ele. Tente aplicar direto ao jframe.

Comment: @diegofm e como eu faria isso?

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo.

Comment: @diegofm Muito obrigado! Como sempre me ajudando e tirando minhas duvidas!

Comment: As vezes demoro um pouco a entender o problema(ou pareço fazer um interrogatório a respeito), mas se tiver um pouco de paciência, estamos ai pra ajudar. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você espera que a ação ocorra na tela, ela deve ser aplicada ao `JFrame` e não ao componente. Da forma como está, só ocorrerá as ações quando o componente estiver em foco, no caso o `JLabel`.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TecladoEvento extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TecladoEvento() {
        initComponents();
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Jogo do Monstro");
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(550, 700));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

                if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "esquerda");
                } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "direita");
                } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "cima");
                } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "baixo");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TecladoEvento().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

A unica modificação que fiz foi remover o `JLabel` e aplicar o listener direto ao `JFrame`, e tudo funcionou normalmente.